# How to resolve error due to Pip in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I tried installing wheel,
But installing some modules in python using pip, every time I get these errors. What might be the issues and how to resolve it?

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\user>cd..

C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd "Program Files"

C:\Program Files>cd Python36

C:\Program Files\Python36>cd Scripts

C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts>pip install wheel
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 21
5, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", li
ne 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 78
4, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in
move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in
clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line
 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python36\\Li
b\\site-packages\\wheel'

C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts>
```

Comment: access denied. so, right click on terminal icon and click on "run as administrator" and then do your above things. I think this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is mentioned here,

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:
```

So **Run the command prompt as administrator**.

In Windows, things can be run as administrator by right-clicking the executable and selecting "Run as Administrator". So, type `"cmd"` in the Start menu, right click `cmd.exe`, and `run it as administrator`.

Comment: Yes, I too think that this will solve your problem. Run it as administrator. If it does not, please edit your question with the updated output.